# stay in active button when click on it in react js ( functional component )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-functional-component

> I want to stay in the section that I click on button and button also stay in background and color that show me ok you are in For example breakfast or lunch or dinner or ...section

```
const Categories = ({ categories, filter }) => {
  return (
    <div className="btn-container">
      {categories.map((categorie, index) => {
        return (
          <button
            type="button"
            className="filter-btn"
            key={index}
            onClick={() => filter(categorie)}
          >
            {categorie}
          </button>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[all section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFcNn.png) [breakfast section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhCCr.png) [shakes section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQt3u.png)

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: when I click the for example on all button  or breakfast button , button be active and show user your in this section

Comment: Take a look at the first answer on this similar questions asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61835816/reactjs-hooks-set-active-buttons

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to save value in another sate and after this you run this map method

```
{categories.filter(name => name.includes(**anotherStatevalue**)).map((categorie, index) => {
        return (
          <button
            type="button"
            className="filter-btn"
            key={index}
            onClick={() => filter(categorie)}
          >
            {categorie}
          </button>
        );
      })}
```

Comment: thanks, in this component I should use useState? and how save value ?